# Spark how to split (key-value list) into key-value pairs

Tags: python, pyspark

Given an RDD with several key-value pairs, where each value is actually a list of values, how do I split the value lists so that I end up with simple key-value pairs?

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
foo = sc.parallelize([(0,[1,1,4]),(1,[3,5])])
bar = foo.map(magic)
bar.collect()
>>>>[(0,1),(0,1),(0,4),(1,3),(1,5)]
```

What would `magic` look like to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
bar=foo.flatMap(lambda l: [(l[0], value) for value in l[1]])
```

I realize that it is a rather simple problem and solution, but I'll leave it up in case anyone else is struggling starting out with pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

Python lets you combine arbitrarily many generator expressions, essentially letting you "unwrap" a nested structure like this. Each "layer" will be a new `for _ in _`

```py
lambda l: [(key, value) for (key, values) in l for value in values]
```

```py
>>> l = [(0,[1,1,4]),(1,[3,5])]
>>> [(key, value) for (key, values) in l for value in values]
[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 4), (1, 3), (1, 5)]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with pyspark. Using your lambda function for magic, I get TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: That means that at some level of the nesting, you tried to "unwrap" an integer type rather than a container type. Can you paste exactly what you tried?

Comment: bar = foo.map(lambda l: [(key, value) for (key, values) in l for value in values])

Comment: Hmmm, I may be out of my depth here. I copied my second snippet from a python interpreter, so assuming you're using Python 3 I think we should see the same behavior. It's possible that pyspark is coming into play here in some way I can't see, in which case my answer probably isn't helpful: my answer is generic Python.